# jquery plugin multitime usage

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have created a tab-slider plugin that, I am using it in my page.

But when I want to use it twice , it just applied to last one.

here is the code:

```
$.fn.tabbed = function(){
height= $(window).height();
children= this.children().eq(0).find('li');
length= children.length;
width= $('.content li').width();
ulwidth=length*width;
ul= this.find("ul.content");

ul.css('width',ulwidth);
children.click(function(){
    margin=$(this).index()*width;
    ul.animate({'margin-left':-margin},1000);
});

}
```

Comment: What is your question actually?? I didn't see any specific question here..

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any local variables, use `var` to declare them and it might work. Specifically, you are overwriting your global `ul` variable any time you use the plugin more than once and that'd cause issues, but please don't just fix that one; there's no reason to use all these globals.